# parseInt(number) notwork

Tags: css, numbers, parseint

I want check if my div have a number and add class css.
I have try this :

```
<div class="test" style="">
   <p class="book"> 24 books</p>
</div>

jQuery('.test').addClass('ok');
var number = parseInt(jQuery(this).find('.book').text(), 10);
var current = 26;
if (current > number)
{
jQuery('.test').addClass('its-ok');
}
```

My class "ok" is add but the class its-ok isn't add.

In jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/8tg9exLw/2/

Comment: Yes i have modified my jsfiddle i'm sorry. But not work if 26 > 24

Comment: Please check the jsFiddle link in the last line in my answer, it works for `26 > 24`.

Answer (score 1):

the result of

```
parseInt(jQuery(this).find('.book').text(), 10);
```

is `NaN` because `$(this).find('book')` is an empty selector (what should be the value of `$(this)` in your context ?)

write instead `parseInt($('.book').text(), 10);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,,,

Add "$(document).ready(function(){});"

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.test').addClass('ok');

var number = parseInt(jQuery(this).find('.book').text(), 10);
var current = 26;
if (current > number)
{
jQuery('.test').addClass('its-ok');
}
});
```

Comment: Hummmm... In jsfiddle the code work but in my code localhost notwork. I think var number not work he no check the number. how to display th value number for view is check

Comment: The code work in jsfiddle but not in my website. i think var number is not checked. It's possible to display 'var number' for viewing the result ?

Comment: I 've found this problem. My elelment "book" change width jquery if the user select a couleur EX : slect your color "blue, green..." if the user select blue "book" display 24 if he select green "book" display 10. Maybe a conflict width another jquery or var number not read the live changement .

Answer (score 0):

**[Updated Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8tg9exLw/3/)**

In the following jQuery code:

```
parseInt(jQuery(this).find('.book').text(), 10);
```

it is not getting what `this` is.

Instead of `this`, I suppose you mean to use `.test`. Check the updated jsFiddle above.

Your if condition is not satisfied because `current < number`.

JS:

```
jQuery('.test').addClass('ok');

var number = parseInt(jQuery('.test').find('.book').text(), 10);

console.log(number);

var current = 2;
if (current > number)
{
    jQuery('.test').addClass('its-ok');
}
else
{
    console.log("If condition not satisfied.");
    // do something here
}
```

**EDIT:** For the parsed integer less than current, check this working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8tg9exLw/4/